# Pandas - convert int to datetime.time and datetime.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I need to perform some subtraction between time data from two different sources.

one format is:

```
05:30:00 <class 'datetime.time'>
```

another format is :

```
2050 (which is indicating 20:50pm)
```

I would like to convert both of them in to datetime.datetime and perform the subtraction in order to find the closest time1 to time2:

```
abs(time1 - time2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first parse the string to datetime and find the differences.

```py
import datetime

first_time = datetime.time(hour = 5, minute = 30, second = 0)
second_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2050', '%H%M')
first_time_with_date = datetime.datetime.combine(second_time, first_time)
second_time - first_time_with_date
```

which gives the following output

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=55200)
```

Comment: the second time is already a 05:30:00 <class 'datetime.time'>. I am confused by the b. Also, when I change to "from datetime import datetime". I could not convert a to datetime.datetime (a = datetime.strptime('2050', '%H%M')
a = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), a)

Comment: if I just want to compare hour and minutes and find the difference, ignore the date difference, how to adjust the code?

Comment: It is already ignoring the date differences. It gives only the time differences. You could verify it by giving different values.

Comment: # test
first_time = datetime.time(5,30,00)
second_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2050', '%H%M')
first_time_with_date = datetime.datetime.combine(second_time, first_time)
first_time2 = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), first_time)
print(second_time - first_time_with_date,type(second_time - first_time_with_date))
print(second_time - first_time2,type(second_time - first_time2)).  The output: 15:20:00 <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
-43809 days, 15:20:00 <class 'datetime.timedelta'> --- due to data structure, I cannot easily assign first_time date using the second_time

Comment: Please edit your question and mention your problem with sample data. I don't understand why you are using `.today()`, if you bothered about only time